# How to prove that there are nilsquare infinitesimals that indistinguishable from zero?

Tags: infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

As is known, non-zero infinitesimals exist. It can be proved.

In the book "A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis" John Bell introduced infinitesimals that indistinguishable from zero. He did it implicitly.

[image]

How did he know that such infinitesimals exist? He didn't prove it.

How to prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not my field, but I imagine you'd want to search up [Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis), perhaps with the word "construction".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-trivial matter.  There is a sketch in the Appendix to Bell's book

> Bell, John L.  A primer of infinitesimal analysis. Second edition.  Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2008. xii+124 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-88718-2; 0-521-88718-6

Here on page one finds:

> In this appendix we sketch the construction of models for smooth infinitesimal
> analysis. We assume here an acquaintance with the basic concepts of category
> theory (see Mac Lane and Moerdijk, 1992 or McLarty, 1992).
> The central concept in the construction of such models is that of a topos. To
> arrive at the concept of a topos, we start with the familiar category **Set** of sets
> whose objects are all sets and whose maps are all functions between them.

Comment: I read in John Bell book's that if $\Delta f = f'(x)dx + o(dx)^2$ then $\varepsilon^2=(dx)^2$ and we set $\varepsilon^2=0$. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: I saw some sources where category theory and toposes are explained. But I found nothing that can be help me. I don't understand how category theory and toposes can help me to prove that nilsquare $\varepsilon$ exist. ? Thanks. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: It seems I start to understand main thing. $\varepsilon$ is defined as a new type of number. $\varepsilon$ isn't "calculate". Is it true? @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, let's leave aside Synthetic Differential Geometry for a moment.  Do you understand the construction of the real number line?

Comment: Yes. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, Can you summarize how it goes?

Comment: Maybe. But I need more details. What exactly is needed? @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, how would you construct the real number line usually denoted $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I'm slightly confused because real number line is just line with points that correspond real numbers. In its turn, real numbers can be constructed from rational numbers (as Dedekind cuts of rational numbers/Cauchy sequences/Decimal representations). The real numbers form an ordered field. This means that methods and rules of elementary arithmetic apply to them. Also there are axioms and other properties for the real numbers.  (If I understood correctly what you meant) @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, OK.  Note that the real numbers are just one possible formalisation of the geometric line.  There is a number of alternatives, including the hyperreals and Bell's $R$.  How would you construct the hyperreals?

Comment: Hyperreal numbers can be constructed from real numbers with addition infinite and infinitesimals. Hyperreal field can be constructed via sequences of reals. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, Could you elaborate a bit on how this is done?

Comment: Define an ordered field which extends $R$ using sequences. For infinitesimal $\varepsilon = (1, 1/2, 1/3, ...)$ and infinite number $\omega = (1, 2, 3, ...)$. For real number $r$$=(r,r,r,...)$ @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, How would you define such an ordered field?

Comment: I define such ordered field with total order. @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, How does one do that exactly?

Comment: For any two values $x$ and $y$, either $x ≤ y$ or $y ≤ x$, and if $x ≤ y$ $∧$ $y ≤ x$ then $x=y$. The total order must also respect the two operations: if $a ≤ b$, then $a + x ≤ b + x$; and if $0 ≤ a$ and $0 ≤ b$ then $0 ≤ a×b.$ @Mikhail Katz

Comment: @Mike_bb, but how do you construct such a total order exactly?  You mentioned earlier that one can use sequences.  If so, will the sequence $(1,-\frac12,\frac13,-\frac14,\frac15,\ldots$ end up being positive or negative in your total order?

Comment: Why do you ask me about hyperreal numbers? :) @Mikhail Katz